# how to get files changed in last 5 minutes

Tags: python

Need to walk the current directory and get the files modified in last 5 mins. I am only starting this and this is what i have so far

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import os,sys,time

dir = os.getcwd() 

print dir


for f in os.walk(dir):
    for i in os.stat(f).st_mtime:
    print i
```

when i run this i get this error

```
for i in os.stat(f).st_mtime:
```

TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, tuple found

I would like to understand whats causing this before i move on

Comment: What line is the error on?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to unpack, join the file to the root directory and compare:

```
import os, time

_dir = os.getcwd()
files = (fle for rt, _, f in os.walk(_dir) for fle in f if time.time() - os.stat(
    os.path.join(rt, fle)).st_mtime < 300)

print(list(files))
```

`os.stat(filename).st_mtime` returns a time which cannot be iterated over, you need to compare that time to the current time, `time.time()` itself returns the seconds since the epoch so you need to compare the difference between `time.time() - os.stat(os.path.join(rt, fle)).st_mtime`  to the amount of minutes in seconds, i.e 300 in your case.

If you are monitoring directories you might find [watchdog](http://pythonhosted.org/watchdog/quickstart.html)  useful, the example in the docs does exactly what you want:

```
import sys
import time
import logging
from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import LoggingEventHandler

if __name__ == "__main__":
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO,
                        format='%(asctime)s - %(message)s',
                        datefmt='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    path = sys.argv[1] if len(sys.argv) > 1 else '.'
    event_handler = LoggingEventHandler()
    observer = Observer()
    observer.schedule(event_handler, path, recursive=True)
    observer.start()
    try:
        while True:
            time.sleep(1)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        observer.stop()
    observer.join()
```

It checks the current directory recursively for changes to files and logs any changes to the console.

Answer (score 6):

`os.walk()` generates tuples, you're trying to use a string.  You want something like:

```
for root, dirs, files in walk(wav_root):
    for f in files:
        filename = root + f
        # Now use filename to call stat().st_mtime
```

I believe.  Wherever you are while iterating with `os.walk()`, joining `root` and `f` will produce the absolute path IIRC.

See here for more: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/os_walk.htm

Answer (score 0):

Try using the 'os', 'glob' and 'time' libraries:

```
import os
import glob
import time

file_list = glob.glob("C:\\path_to_files\\*.")
for file in file_list:
    if (int(time.time()) - int(os.stat(file).st_mtime) < 300):
        # Do something with this file
```